# Get quantile for each value

Tags: r, quantile

Is there an implemented (!) function in R which gives you the empirical quantile for each value? I couldn't find any ...

Let's say we have x

```
x = c(1,3,4,2)
```

I want to have the quantile of each element.

```
[1] 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0.5
```

Comment: This code was useful to me `x/length(x)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `ecdf()` function:

```
ecdf(x)(x)
[1] 0.25 0.75 1.00 0.50
```

`ecdf(x)` creates a function, and you pass the elements of `x` to that function. The syntax admittedly looks strange

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!